# When MSTest fails in TestInitialize, why doesn't TestCleanup get executed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mstest

I have a base class that has a `TestInitialize` and a `TestCleanup` in it. I then have other test classes which inherit from this class. The `TestCleanup` is supposed to perform certain actions when a test from the derived class fails.

The `TestCleanup` gets executed when the test fails in the actual test. However, when the test fails in the `TestInitialize`, the `TestCleanup` doesn't even get executed. Why does this happen and is there a way to get the `TestCleanup` to get called anyway?

I don't think that the fact that the `TestInitialize` and `TestCleanup` are in a base class is at all causing this issue, I just wanted to give more information just in case it was.

Comment: Can you explain more about why you are getting exceptions in your TestInitialize? This is not something I would normally expect to be happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known issue. It looks like it has been reported to Microsoft connect.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/694337/testcleanup-method-does-not-run-when-it-should

Comment: Thanks. As a workaround I just took the code out and put it in another method. Now I check if my assertion will fail and if it will I call that method and then call an assert.fail().

Comment: That was fixed in MsTest v2. https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/250

Extract from the link: This was a conscious compat break to give unit test writers a choice to cleanup partially initialized methods.

Comment: Microsoft Connect has been retired so the contents of the hyperlink can now only be found here: http://web.archive.org/web/20140310065725/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/694337/testcleanup-method-does-not-run-when-it-should

Answer (score 2):

In my Opinion you shouldn't write code in the TestInitialize that can fail.

If you think what you are doing is correct, and you just want to catch it if it fails, why not wrapping the TestInitialize with a try-catch and call your code or TestCleanup on exception?

Comment: These are coded-ui tests. In my TestInitialize I try to open the application and assert that the application actually opened. This in my opinion makes sense because why should I be recalling this code in every test. My TestCleanup tries to kill the application, which is necesary if the application is in a bad state

Comment: @ilhbh, maybe a little late, but `TestInitialize` does get called with every test. If you want to call it only once you need to use `ClassInitialize` instead.

Answer (score 0):

We have a try catch in our TestInitialize. Its for coded UI tests and if you dont kill the application/browser you will have multiple windows open next time you connect to the testenvironment (if you are deploying and testing on one of those).

There are alot of things that can go wrong in the testinitialize when talking about CodedUI so use a TryCatch, and call the TestCleanup manually in the Catch. More correct is that in the Catch we kill the application/browser in the same way that the TestCleanup would do. We dont call the cleanup function. But if you can, then do so.